# How to set background image for the frame?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I know in [this article](http://wp7-developer.com/quick-tip/quick-tip-ensuring-the-background-color-remains-consistent-during-a-transition/) they set the background color using the steps followed. I was wondering if there was a way of using an image instead of a Color. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = 
new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyApp;component/Images/Backgrounds/myimage.jpg"));
Rootframe.Background = brush;
```

Has anyone seen if this is possible? Or is it restricted to Colors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to have a go and got it working. The only catch is, it's a bit of a workaround since there seems to be some strange behaviour with the `ImageOpened` event. Basically, the `ImageOpened` event of the `Brush` doesn't get called when you assign the background to the frame. Strangely, it does get called when you assign it to an element. So I just created a hidden button and assigned the brush to that (to force the `ImageOpened` event to fire). I then assigned it to the frame and it works for me. Seems like a bug, but the workaround below works for me.

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();

brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/myImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
//hide the fake button and set the brush to be its background
button1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
button1.Background = brush;

//assign it to the frame (or using RootFrame in your case)
var frame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
frame.Background = brush;
```

Comment: Try it with an image in your existing app instead of a separate assembly. Then use `new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Backgrounds/myimage.jpg"));` with build type set to `Content`.

Comment: Unfortnuately that didn't work either. It's strange because I was able to set a System Color and a custom Color. Might be one of those things though that was left out.

Comment: I tried what you said but I still can't get it to work. Mind posting some more code. Sorry about that. Also am I still supposed to set the image to Content or should I go back to Resource?

Comment: There's no more code to post, that's pretty much it from a new project (added a new button on the page to fake the event). I placed it in the my page's `Loaded` event. If you're referencing the image from the same assembly, then you can set it as content. I don't have the toolkit you're using so I don't have `RootFrame`. Instead, I just used the app's main frame and my background was the same on all pages.

Comment: I got it working although for some reason the button never worked. Instead I put an image control, and on the Image_Opened event I set the brush.ImageSource = Image.Source. Then I set the RootFrame.Background = brush and It works perfectly. Thanks for your patience and awesome feedback. +1

Comment: @loyalpenguin - No problem :) I'm guessing it's a bug of some sort which explains the random behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
RootFrame.Background = App.Current.Resources["MainBackground"] as ImageBrush;
```

works for me. You'll need the following in your resources dictionary in `App.xaml`

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="MainBackground" ImageSource="/resources/MainBackground.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `CreateOption` to `None` or `BackgroundCreation` and wait while image is loaded:

```
 BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/MyApp;component/Images/Backgrounds/myimage.jpg"))
 {
      CreateOptions = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions.None
 };
 image.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
 {
      brush.ImageSource = image;
      App.RootFrame.Background = brush;
 };
```

Comment: @Ky6opr I added that but still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: I added that but the transition screen is still black. I'm going to see if I can can get some more details from AppHub and see what I can find out. If I get an answer I'll post it here.

Comment: Try to load image into `Image` control on the page. Issue can be in another place...